# How to determine which dependency is responsible for versioning in maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I try to find out, which of my versions in my project is responsible for a version in my final build. I updated the `Spring starter` to `2.6.6` and this should update the subdependencies to version `5.3.18` but there are still dependencies with `5.3.15`. So currently I try to figure out which dependency is forcing maven to use the `5.3.15`. The `mvn dependency:tree -verbose` [flag](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) doesn't really help. I only get the information that maven is still using `5.3.15`.

Is there a way to let maven print out which version creates the conflict of versioning and forces maven to use the old one?

Comment: ah ok, i used the verbose flag wrong. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using InteliJ or Eclipse (or Eclipse based) IDE there is a "Maven Helper" plugin. In Eclipse it usually comes as part of the base installation and in IntelliJ you have to install it. but with this plugin when you open your pom.xml you get an option to search your pom really nicely. (pom view called "Dependency analyzer"). And you can easily see  which dependency and which version comes from where and which other versions of the same dependency are suppressed. It really made my life much easier when I searched for version conflicts. I strongly recommend it. See this [link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper) for InteliJ

Answer (score 0):

Try using `maven dependency:tree`, search for your dependency name and see what are the different versions